# TableLayoutPanel has incorrect row height

Tags: c#, winforms, autosize, tablelayoutpanel

I have auto-sized 2x2 table layout and long auto-sized labels in each cell.
This layout is in other table layout with no-auto-sized cells.
Minimal project to reproduce the problem:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TestForms {
    static class Program {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main() {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new TestForm());
        }
    }

    class TestForm : Form {
        public TestForm() {
            var childPanel = new TableLayoutPanel();
            var label8 = new Label();
            var label9 = new Label();
            var label10 = new Label();
            var label7 = new Label();
            var rootPanel = new TableLayoutPanel();

            childPanel.AutoSize = true;
            childPanel.AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
            childPanel.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Silver;
            childPanel.ColumnCount = 2;
            childPanel.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, 50F));
            childPanel.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, 50F));
            childPanel.Controls.Add(label8, 1, 0);
            childPanel.Controls.Add(label9, 0, 1);
            childPanel.Controls.Add(label10, 1, 1);
            childPanel.Controls.Add(label7, 0, 0);
            childPanel.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
            childPanel.RowCount = 2;
            childPanel.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle());
            childPanel.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle());

            label8.AutoSize = true;
            label8.Text = "2ggggggggggggggggg";

            label9.AutoSize = true;
            label9.Text = "label9";

            label10.AutoSize = true;
            label10.Text = "label10";

            label7.AutoSize = true;
            label7.Text = "label7";

            rootPanel.ColumnCount = 1;
            rootPanel.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, 100F));
            rootPanel.Controls.Add(childPanel, 0, 0);
            rootPanel.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            rootPanel.RowCount = 1;
            rootPanel.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, 100F));

            ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(205, 197);
            Controls.Add(rootPanel);
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following result:

[image: Screenshot]

Why last row got the wrong height? Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, seems like you have hit some bug since it doesn't happen if some of the labels `AutoSize` is `false`, or making the first column style `SizeType.AutoSize` etc.

You can use the following workaround. It's ugly, but that's the only way I've found. The idea is to add invisible row containing fake `Label` with `AutoSize` set to `false`. For instance, after setting up the normal layout, add the following lines:

```
childPanel.RowCount++;
childPanel.RowStyles.Add(new RowStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 0));
childPanel.Controls.Add(new Label { AutoSize = false }, 0, childPanel.RowCount - 1);
```